# joining larger volumes of table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to join three larger tables in oracle. TableA has 370 million rows, TableB has 370 million rows and the master table TableM has 600 000 rows. TableM is the master table of the other two tables TableA and TableB.

My query was like

```
Select A.MasterId, B.Date1
  FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B on B.MasterId= A.MasterId
INNER JOIN TableM M ON M.MasterId= A.MasterId
```

When I execute the above query, its taking a long time. I wanted to split the query execution with WHERE clause by taking the values of five years data. We have total of 25 years of data, so five times I can execute the below query and insert the values to Temp table.

My approaches are.

Approach 1:

Using UNION operator, I can combine the result set and insert the values to Temp table. It took too long.

```
Select A.MasterId, B.Date1
  FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B on B.MasterId= A.MasterId
INNER JOIN TableM M ON M.MasterId= A.MasterId
WHERE M.Date > '01-JAN-1985' and M.Date <'01-JAN-1990'
UNION ALL
Select A.MasterId, B.Date1
  FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B on B.MasterId= A.MasterId
INNER JOIN TableM M ON M.MasterId= A.MasterId
WHERE M.Date > '01-JAN-1990' and M.Date <'01-JAN-1995'
```

.....

Approach 2:

Tried to insert the 5 years data to temp table by using bulk collect but it failed.

Is there any other way to handle this problem?

Comment: 1) What are the indexes involved? 2) Are the tables partitioned? 3) How does the explain plan look like? 4) And don't use PL/SQL, it will be much slower than SQL. 5) `'01-JAN-1985'` is **not** a **DATE**, it is a **string**. 6) what is the data type?

Comment: Do you happen to have one smaller table ? You could UAE with option in select if you have one smaller table. Could you supply tables size ?

Comment: Hi Lalit, Thanks for your prompt reply. Find the below answer for your qns.

Comment: 5.SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 2,041,664  Bytes: 58,047,151,824  Cardinality: 14,929,823

Answer (score 1):

A full join over these 3 tables would result in 8.2140E+22 records, which seems like an unwieldy large dataset and that is also why it takes a loooooong time.
What would be the use of such a select?

For insert, use a simple INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...
Performance should be much better than using pl/sql with bulk collect.